# AWS SSH Connection Issue: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to establish a AWS Server ssh connection using the command:

ssh -v -i abc-key-pair-nvirginia.pem admin@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
(tried root/ubuntu/ec2-user instead of admin too)

Log Trace:

```
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1x:xx:aa:aa:aa:aa:a0:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:xx:xx
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/abc/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: abc@abc.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: abc-key-pair-nvirginia.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have seen few of the links on internet but not able to figure out how to resolve this. Can someone please suggest on how to debug this ?
Thanks,

Comment: What Linux distro is the nstance? Is this the first time you are connecting after the instance launch?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14. I created the account yesterday and have tried multiple times since then but with same error.

Comment: Use ubuntu@host. Are you sure you are using the correct private key?

Comment: I have tried ubuntu/root/ec2-user/admin but same error. This .pem file got auto downloaded on my system. I am using that itself.

Comment: @helloV Can you pls tell how can i verify my private & public key values ?

Comment: Try `ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pub` and compare key.pub with the keypair you used when you launched the instance.

Comment: Tried this. Value of key.pem file matches with 'ssh public key on AWS Console'. Not sure how to verify key.pub value.

Comment: Thanks @helloV , this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If your using a Ubuntu instance use the username, `ubuntu`. Example below:

```
ssh -v -i abc-key-pair-nvirginia.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

If that fails then you'll need to check that your instance has been started with the key pair that your using.

Also, make sure that your key file has the correct permissions. You can set those using:

```
chmod 600 abc-key-pair-nvirginia.pem
```

Comment: Ok - have you checked your AWS Console to make sure the key matches the server?

Comment: Which key needs to be verified ? Can you please be a little more elaborate here, if possible ?

Comment: When you created the EC2 Instance, the AWS Console / API asked which Key/Pair you wished to use. Check to make sure the key pair you specified is the same as the one your attempting to logon using.

Comment: Tried ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pub. Value of key.pem file matches with 'ssh public key on AWS Console'. Not sure how to verify key.pub value.